# How to set a x:Name to a control in a CollectionView / ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to give a name to an ImageButton in xaml but it doesn't work because of the fact that it is in a CollectionView, does someone know how to give a name to the control ?

What I'm trying to do:

Every item in the list has a heart button and I want to be able to click on the heart to save that item, to give it a little animation I wanted to give the ImageButton a name and do something with it in the code behind.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi! You are not able to do that by using a name. You will have to use events/commands fired when clicked. Right now how are you handing the click event?

Comment: Oh I see, I'm handling the click with a command in the view model but I wanted to do some UI things with a Clicked event

Comment: Do you want to edit your post and add some code and explain a little more what you want to achieve? We might help you a little better

Answer (score 0):

Because CollectionView is cyclic, it is wrong if you define x:name in ImageButton.

According to your description, I wrote a small example for your reference. It creates a **CollectionView** in xaml with an **ImageButton** inside.

When the ImageButton is **clicked**, the ImageButton and Lable information in this row will be changed.

Here is the xaml code(Created a CollectionView containing an ImageButton and a Label inside):

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView x:Name="mytest">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
                    <ImageButton Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" Source="xxx.jpg" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"></ImageButton>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<string> observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Simulation data
        observableCollection.Add("aaa");
        observableCollection.Add("bbb");
        observableCollection.Add("ccc");
        mytest.ItemsSource = observableCollection;
    }

    private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (((sender as ImageButton).Parent as StackLayout).Children[0] as Label).Text = "Clicked and modified";
        (((sender as ImageButton).Parent as StackLayout).Children[1] as ImageButton).Source = "xxx1.jpg";    
    }
}
```

In the ImageButton_Clicked method, use `(sender as ImageButton).Parent` to get the upper view, and then use `.Children[x]` to get all the information inside the StackLayout and modify it.